# FFTW on Mac OS X Mavericks issues

Tags: c, macos, fftw

I am sure this is a simple issue, but I am having a rough time getting in done. I am using this code snippet from http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_2.html. I have the library installed (via homebrew). The include folder (/usr/local/include) has

```
fftw3.f
fftw3.f03
fftw3.h
fftw3l.f03
fftw3q.f03
```

Here is the code snippet from the site. I have tried it with both fttw.h and fttw3.h

```
#include <fftw.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv){
 fftw_complex in[N], out[N];
 fftw_plan p;

 p = fftw_create_plan(N, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

 fftw_one(p, in, out);

 fftw_destroy_plan(p);  

     return 0;
}
```

It keeps throwing

```
fftwtest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found
#include <fftw3.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Not this error, but the one you're going to have next: That code uses FFTW's old version 2 API, but you have the current (backwards incompatible) version installed. Read up on http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc

Comment: If you just want to calculate FFTs on OS X then you already have the Accelerate framework available, i.e. you don't need to use FFTW unless you want your code to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` aren't on the default header search path anymore in Mavericks.  You'll need to add them with `-I` and `-L` flags, respectively.

Comment: Interesting change...not that I'd noticed the old behaviour either.

Comment: I had to change some project makefiles here.  I don't like it, but I don't make the decisions, so...

Comment: How do you add these?

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to install pyfftw via the following, all in one terminal session:

```
brew install fftw
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/include"
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"
pip install pyfftw
```

Comment: This worked for me, with one small tweak: I had to use `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"` (with `/lib` instead of `/include`).

Comment: This worked for me to install the latest version of pyFFTW on macOS Mojave:

`export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"`, `export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"`, `pip install git+git://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW.git`

Comment: I had to do. export CFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include -Wno-implicit-function-declaration"

Answer (score 1):

You need the right compiler flags.  Add `/usr/local/include` to your header search path.  This is done with the `-I` flag for the compiler, or if you are using Xcode, you can set it in the project settings.